# Permutations / Probability sitting around a table

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

James and his 5 friends(Kyle,Tom,Bob,Michael,John) are about to sit around a round table there are 6 sits at the table.

What is the probability James will sit between Bob and Michael ?

My solution
A= number of ways James can sit between Bob and Michael

B= total number of ways they can sit

As James, Bob and Michael technically sit next together we can consider them as single unit
A=4!* 2! The 2! Is the number of ways Bob and Michael can swap.

B= Total number of ways the can all sit is (n-1)!
I.e 5!

P= A//B
Which is 2/5

Answer (score 2):

That is not the right answer. Instead break the circle at James so the remaining five people form a line; there are $2\cdot3!$ seating arrangements out of $5!$ where Bob and Michael sit at the line's ends, and hence next to James in the full circle (the other three people may be permuted arbitrarily). Thus the answer is $\frac{2\cdot3!}{5!}=\frac1{10}$.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to do (n-1)! Ways  for the number of favourable cases, so the numerator should 3!*2!

Comment: @RoboJumble Please accept my answer if you will, no?

Answer (score 1):

By convention, in a circular permutation,  only the relative order of the objects matters.

Seat James.  We will use him as our reference point.  Relative to James, there are indeed $5!$ ways to arrange his friends around the table as we proceed clockwise around the table from James.

For the favorable cases, once James is seated, there are $2$ ways to arrange Bob and Michael next to James.  That leaves three seats for Kyle, Tom, and John.  They can be seated in those three seats in $3!$ ways as we proceed clockwise around the table from James.  Hence, the number of favorable cases is $2 \cdot 3!$.

Therefore, the probability that James will sit between Bob and Michael if the six people are seated randomly around the table is
$$\frac{2 \cdot 3!}{5!}$$
In your attempt, you forgot to use a reference point for the favorable cases.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you mean that the three people are ordered [Bob, James, Michael] or [Michael, James, Bob].

You can express the probability as

$$\frac{N}{D},$$

where $D = (5!)$.

That is, since the table is round, you can arbitrarily designate anyone as the head of the table (i.e. the twelve-o'clock position).  Then you will have $(5)$ remaining people to permute.

So, based on the above discussion, the problem reduces to computing $N$.

Think of the $(3)$ people, Michael, James, Bob, as forming one **fused** unit.  Then, in effect, you have $(4)$ units to permute around the table.  Namely, the fused unit and the other $(3)$ units.

Since the table is round, this can be done in $(4-1)!$ ways.

Further, the fused unit permits $(2!)$ internal permutations of the three people inside the unit, since James must be in the middle.

Putting this all together, the probability is

$$\frac{[(4-1)!] \times 2!}{(6-1)!}.$$

An alternative way of computing $N$ is to arbitrarily decide that James will go in the twelve-o'clock position.  Then, Bob, Micheal can be permuted in $(2)!$ ways around James, and then the $(3)$ remaining people can be permuted in $(3!)$ ways in the three remaining seats.